# Circle Meter Type UI in android?

Tags: android-layout, android

[image]

As here One static Image is shown inside back. But How could we implement that coloring rounded portion with one end is Starting RED and Ended with Green and after some Time duration.Please Let me know how to implement it.

[image][image]

Glad even u can help a bit.
Thank You in Advance.

Comment: not much sure but i think you can achieve this using OpneGL or canvas.

Comment: Please Provide me some Reference or Any Idea to get such UI. Thank you  for Reply.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at these links:-

http://atstechlab.wordpress.com/2010/07/30/gauge-and-dial-widget-for-android/

http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/

https://github.com/CodeAndMagic/GaugeView

These will get you started !!

Comment: Thank you for the Reply.Here what u have Provided me is also meter but i want to implement without using that clock hand shown in your examples. I want meter which is Contiguously Filling with colored area  as given in my example images.

Comment: those changes can be done in canvas that are used while drawing this gauge, so shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Give me some related application example as Canvas implementation is new for me.

Comment: you can google and you will find enormous amount of tutorials